# what should cron.log permissions be?

Tags: server, permissions, cron

Ubuntu 18.04LTS server

My /var/log/cron.log is set to:

-rwxrwxr-x 1 syslog adm 0 Dec  4 07:12 /var/log/cron.log

Every time rsyslog starts, I get a file permission error on /var/log/cron.log:

Jan  3 11:00:01 servername rsyslogd: file '/var/log/cron.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]

What is this file's permission supposed to be ?

Comment: Hmmm. A stock install of Ubuntu lacks a separate cron.log - cron output goes to syslog instead.

Comment: Permissions and ownership should be the same as syslog: `-rw-r----- syslog    adm`. Please check /var/log permissions and ownership also: `drwxrwxr-x root syslog`

Answer (score 0):

`/var/log/cron.log` is obsolete, since `cron` logs via `syslog`. Did you install a non-standard `cron`?

See if any process has `/var/log/cron.log` open with

```
sudo lsof /var/log/cron.log
```

This *should* show no processes,

E.g.:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ sudo lsof /var/log/backupninja.log
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
walt@bat:~(1)$ sudo lsof /var/log/syslog
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
rsyslogd 1534 syslog    6w   REG    8,5    15948 391680 /var/log/syslog
```

If `lsof` does show a process with `/var/log/cron.log` open, you'll need to adjust, reconfigure or terminate the process.

If no running process has `/var/log/cron.log` open, simply delete the file:

```
sudo rm /var/log/cron.log
```

`cron` logs should be viewed with `journalctl`, The New Way of Unified Logging. Please read `man journalctl`.

```
# do this once
sudo adduser $USER systemd-journal

# add to ~/.bash_aliases or ~/.bashrc
# tsjou "18-11-01 01:55:28" for journalctl --since
alias tsjou="date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"
alias jc=journalctl
# record beginning for journalctl
alias jstart="JSTART_TIME=\"\$(tsjou)\""
alias jend="journalctl --since=\"\$JSTART_TIME\""
alias jc5="journalctl --since=\"-5 minutes\""
alias jc10="journalctl --since=\"-10 minutes\""
```

Then, view the `cron` log with

```
jc -b 0  /usr/sbin/cron
jc -b 0  /usr/sbin/anacron
```

Comment: My install is default 18.04 with no add-ons or anything related to logging that I did intentionally.  /var/log is: root:syslog 0775 and the files in /var/log are various ownerships and permissions, but specifically cron.log is syslog:adm 0775 and syslog is syslog:adm 0640